# Eclipse not working after installing plugin

Tags: eclipse

I installed php-development-tools & html-editor-wtp to eclipse , but after that eclipse not working.
[eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFmH7.png)

also it shows these errors:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAjSe.png)

My eclipse :neon.3(4.6.3)

error:
An internal error occurred during: "Initialize metrics".
com/genuitec/eclipse/core/gsdc/GSDCController

after I install plugin eclipse show a balck page without any icon to click

my installed software:

```html
  Darkest Dark Theme 1.8.0.201705081336 com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group Genuitec, LLC
    Eclipse Platform 4.6.3.v20170301-0400 org.eclipse.platform.feature.group Eclipse.org
    Genuitec Base 1.8.0.201705081336 com.genuitec.eclipse.common.core.base.feature.feature.group Genuitec, LLC
  Darkest Dark Theme - Icon Designer 1.8.0.201705081336 com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.designer.feature.feature.group Genuitec, LLC
  Eclipse SDK 4.6.3.M20170301-0400 org.eclipse.sdk.ide Eclipse.org
    Eclipse p2 Provisioning Developer Resources 2.2.203.v20170131-1444 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.source.feature.group Eclipse.org
    Eclipse Project SDK 4.6.3.v20170301-0400 org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group Eclipse.org
    Equinox p2, Provisioning for IDEs. 2.2.203.v20170131-1444 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group Eclipse.org - Equinox
  Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.8.2.v201702270442 org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    Eclipse JSON Editors and Tools 1.0.2.v201612232230 org.eclipse.wst.json_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    Eclipse Web Developer Tools User Documentation 3.8.2.v201610032207 org.eclipse.wst.web_userdoc.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.8.2.v201702270442 org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    JavaScript Development Tools 2.0.200.v201612211424 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    WST Common UI 3.8.0.v201701191735 org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    WST Server UI 3.3.655.v201611072017 org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
    WST Web Core 3.8.2.v201702270442 org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Gluon Tools 2.4.0 com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.feature.group Gluon
    e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.3.0.201603030809 org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org
  Marketplace Client 1.4.2.v20160210-2005 org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group Eclipse Marketplace Client
    Equinox p2, Discovery UI support 1.0.401.v20160901-1335 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - Equinox
  Marketplace Client (Sources) 1.4.2.v20160210-2005 org.eclipse.epp.mpc.source.feature.group Eclipse Marketplace Client
  PHP Development Tools (PDT) 4.3.1.201703301037 org.eclipse.php.feature.group Eclipse PDT
    Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Core Frameworks 5.7.1.201703020501 org.eclipse.dltk.core.feature.group Eclipse DLTK
    Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Core Lucene Index Frameworks 5.7.1.201703020501 org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene.feature.group Eclipse DLTK
  PHP Development Tools (PDT) Composer Support 4.3.1.201703301037 org.eclipse.php.composer.feature.group Eclipse PDT
  PHP Development Tools (PDT) Mylyn Integration 4.3.1.201703301037 org.eclipse.php.mylyn.feature.group Eclipse PDT
    Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Mylyn Integration 5.7.1.201703020501 org.eclipse.dltk.mylyn.feature.group Eclipse DLTK
  PHP Development Tools (PDT) Smart Import 4.3.1.201703301037 org.eclipse.php.importer.feature.group Eclipse PDT
  Swing Designer 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.swing.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder Core 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder Core UI 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.core.ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.layout.group.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder Java Core 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.core.java.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  Swing Designer Documentation 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.swing.doc.user.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder Core Documentation 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.doc.user.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  SWT Designer 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.rcp.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment 3.12.3.v20170301-0400 org.eclipse.pde.feature.group Eclipse.org
    SWT Designer Core 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.swt.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  SWT Designer Documentation 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  SWT Designer SWT_AWT Support 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.rcp.SWT_AWT_support.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  SWT Designer XWT Support (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.xwt.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
    WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.core.xml.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
  WindowBuilder CSS Support 1.9.0 org.eclipse.wb.css.feature.feature.group Eclipse WindowBuilder
```

Comment: could you please describe this issue in text (it should be clear without pictures)? post the error messages and describe what's happening. also, please mention your full eclipse setup - plugin list and version - it might be helpful. PS: why not use the [Eclipse PHP package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/neon3) which has already been configured to contain those plugins

Comment: The error is caused by some Genuitec classes, typically provided by the "Darkest dask theme". You should refer to Genuitec support.